# What's the standard makefile idiom for trying different ways to make a target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that uses a source file from the internet. There are two locations where the file resides, neither of which I consider very dependable, so I also keep a local copy. So the relevant lines of my makefile look like:

```
src.c:
    wget -nv http://location.com/$@ || wget -nv http://otherplace.com/$@ || cp local/$@ .

src.o: src.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

Is this the "right way" to do this? What if there are multiple steps in each different way of creating the target - how do I tell make "Try A. If A fails, try B. If B fails, ..."?

Comment: As far as I know, Make can't verify that these remote files exist or check their timestamps, so you probably can't do much better than what you have. But if you have a local copy of the source, why bother with remote files at all? And if the remote versions are preferable (e.g. more up-to-date), why not update the local version while you're at it?

Comment: Expanding on what @Beta said I think the best thing to do is have the local copy have a `force` prereq and then always fetch the remote resources to temporary files and compare timestamps against the local copy and then update the local copy when the remote source is newer.

Comment: Etan beat me to it by a few minutes.  Etan says nicely "Expanding on what Beta said", when in fact he disagrees.  I also disagree with Beta.  Yes Nate _can_ do much better than what he had.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Beta - although it's possible that the remote file could be updated, the primary reason for downloading it is to make it explicit that the source is not _my_ file and to have a record of where I got it. I do have other code that I didn't include that updates my local copy if applicable. I also have to patch the original, so I keep an un-modified version in a sub-folder. Mark Galeck's answer works as a template for me.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: The only thing we seem to disagree about is what "much better" entails.

Comment: @Beta Well my argument is this.  Previously, the code was _always_ rebuilding _everything_ on the account that something new _might_ have become available.  The _worst_ possible situation with GNU Make.  My code is rebuilding _nothing_ that does not have to be rebuilt based on what _is_ available.  The _best_ possible situation.  I argue that the difference between "all possible false positive errors, no use of capabilities of Make", and "no errors of any kind" is "much better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do is this:

```
.PHONY: phony
src.c: phony
    if (wget -nv http://location.com/$@ -O $@.temp) && ! diff $@.temp $@ >/dev/null; then \
     mv $@.temp $@; \
    fi
```

I shortened your command to a single `wget` but you can put whatever you want there, including a sequence of `||`s to achieve "try this, if not, try that etc".  Just make sure it outputs to a temporary file (and does not hang indefinitely !) .

It is in fact important to use `phony` here, and not only `.PHONY`.  Can you see why?

Also, with this method, there is no longer a need to keep another "local" copy and/or use `cp`.  Your target `src.c` *is* your "local copy" - the latest one you were able to successfully get from the Internet.

Comment: My answer is in fact the same as Etan comment.  I am sorry, I did not plagiarize. I noticed his comment after having debugged my answer.  I would gladly upvote Etan's answer.

Comment: I think I see ... the `.PHONY` line lets `phony` be a pre-req for `src.c` without being an actual file. `src.c` will be "remade" every time the makefile is entered with a target that depends on `src.c`, but src.o will only be re-compiled if `src.c` changes - that is, the download succeeds and is different from the local copy.

Comment: Actually, upon reflection I'm not seeing the trap you're implying is there. How would one _incorrectly_ use `.PHONY` without `phony`?

Comment: @NateT well, one is tempted to just say `.PHONY:src.c` , that would be OK for `src.c` but bad for `src.o`